# Proof of Prime Number Theorem

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I am looking for a detailed proof of the Prime Number Theorem using analytic methods (that is, using $\zeta(s)$). What is a good reference to read?

Comment: Second result from Google: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/CV/CV7.pdf

Comment: Hardy and Wright is good.

Comment: The Prime Number Theorem by Jameson is also good.